# RAID Problem with 2 SATA

Tags: raid, sata, raid-1

I have two 160 gig SATA drives in a RAID 1 configuration.

The other day, I rebooted my PC and found that the RAID array had 
somehow spontaneously been split into two, i.e. each drive had its own 
array, each of which was listed as "Degraded".

One of the drives boots into Windows normally (although the first time I 
got the message "Windows has recovered from a serious error" ). The other 
drive fails to boot, so clearly has become out of sync with the first 
drive.

I've been advised to go into the RAID setup for the second disk and 
choose the "Clear Disk" option, then rebuild the array based on the 
contents of the first disk. Does anyone know how long this kind of thing 
typically takes? When I tried it, there was no on-screen indication that 
it was doing anything, and I couldn't hear any disk activity. It 
remained like this for 5 hours before I gave up and reset.

The motherboard is a MSI K8N Neo2.

Comment: "Does anyone know how long this kind of thing typically takes?" how long is a piece of string? i.e. how big are the drives and more important, how much disk space is being used on the 'good' drive? also, SATA 3 is faster than SATA 2, which in turn is faster than SATA 1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave this computer with no RAID setup to my nephew... I close this question since I've spent to much time on it! That almost got me nuts!